# how to adjust size of font in all text

Tags: fontsize

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed, etoolbox}
\colorlet{framecolor}{VioletRed4}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2!60}
\usepackage{thmtools} %
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\color{Firebrick2}}  % sets colour of chapters
\sectionfont{\color{Chartreuse4}}
\subsectionfont{\color{blue}}
%talwin majzo2at
%\usepackage{sectsty}%
%\chapterfont{\color{Firebrick2}}
%\usepackage{titlesec}%%%%%% <---------addendum
%\titleformat{\section}%%%%%% <---------addendum
%{\color{Chartreuse4}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}%%%%%% <---------addendum
%{\color{Chartreuse4}\thesection}{1.5em}{}%%%%%% <---------addendum
%\titleformat{\subsection}%%%%%% <---------addendum
%{\color{Firebrick3}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}%%%%%% <---------addendum
%{\color{Firebrick3}\thesection}{1.5em}{}%%%%%% <---------addendum


\makeatletter
\define@key{thmdef}{frame}[{}]{%
 \thmt@trytwice{}{%
 \RequirePackage{framed}%
 \RequirePackage{thm-patch}%
    \def\FrameCommand{\fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}
 \addtotheorempreheadhook[\thmt@envname]{%
 \begin{framed}}%
 \addtotheorempostfoothook[\thmt@envname]{\end{framed}}%
 }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=-6pt, 
    spacebelow=6pt, 
    headfont=\normalfont\bfseries, 
    bodyfont = \normalfont,
    postheadspace=1em, 
    qed=$\blacksquare$, 
    headpunct={:}]{myproofstyle} %<---- change this name
\declaretheorem[name={Proof}, style=myproofstyle, unnumbered]{Proof}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=6pt, 
    spacebelow=6pt, 
    headfont=\bfseries,
    notefont=\bfseries, 
    notebraces={(}{)}, 
    bodyfont=\itshape,
    postheadspace=1em,
    headpunct={:}]{mystyle}

    \declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=6pt, 
    spacebelow=6pt, 
    headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
    notefont=\mdseries\bfseries, 
    notebraces={({)}}, 
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    postheadspace=1em,
    postheadhook = {\hspace{0mm}\newline},%
    headpunct={:},]{myst}

\declaretheorem[name={Théorème}, style=mystyle,numberwithin=section]{thm}
\declaretheorem[frame,name={Lemme}, style=mystyle,numberwithin=section]{lema}
\declaretheorem[frame,name={Définition}, style=mystyle,numberwithin=section]{defi}
\declaretheorem[frame,name={Corollaire}, style=mystyle,numberwithin=section]{coro}
\declaretheorem[frame,name={Proposition}, style=mystyle,numberwithin=section]{props}
\declaretheorem[frame,name={Vocabulaire}, style=mystyle,numberwithin=section]{voc}
\declaretheorem[name={Preuve}, style=myst,numbered=no]{preuve}
\declaretheorem[name={Remarque}, style=myst,numberwithin=section]{remark}
\declaretheorem[name={Remarques}, style=myst,numberwithin=section]{remarks}
\declaretheorem[name={Exemple}, style=myst,numberwithin=section]{exemple}
\declaretheorem[name={Exemples}, style=myst,numbered=no]{exemples}
\declaretheorem[name={Méthode}, style=mystyle,numberwithin=section]{methode}
\declaretheorem[name={Méthodes}, style=mystyle,numbered=no]{methodes}
\declaretheorem[name={Notation}, style=mystyle,numbered=no]{notation}






\AtBeginEnvironment{defi}{\colorlet{framecolor}{black}
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{orange!15}}
\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][1cm]{\mathrel{%
   \hbox{\rule[\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]{#1}{.4pt}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}
   \AtBeginEnvironment{voc}{\colorlet{framecolor}{black}
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{LightSkyBlue2!25}}
    \AtBeginEnvironment{props}{\colorlet{framecolor}{black}
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{Yellow1!15}}
     \AtBeginEnvironment{coro}{\colorlet{framecolor}{black}
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{Yellow1!15}}
    \AtBeginEnvironment{lema}{\colorlet{framecolor}{black}
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{Yellow1!15}}

\makeatletter

\setbox0\hbox{$\xdef\scriptratio{\strip@pt\dimexpr
    \numexpr(\sf@size*65536)/\f@size sp}$}

\newcommand{\myscriptarrow}[1][1cm]{{%
    \hbox{\rule[\scriptratio\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]
               {\scriptratio\dimexpr#1\relax}{\scriptratio\dimexpr.4pt\relax}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\let\f@size\sf@size\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatother
\newcommand*{\QED}{\hfill\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}%Heron

\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{dsfont}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Notion d'extension de corps }
\section{Extension d'anneau}
\begin{defi}
Soit $A$ un anneau, on appel \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{extension}}  de $A$ tout anneau $B$
tel que $A$ est une sous-anneau de $B$. Dans ce cas on note \textcolor{blue}{$B/A$} ou \textcolor{blue}{$B:A$} ou \textcolor{blue}{$A\myarrow B$}.
\end{defi}
\section{Extension de corps}
Maintenant on introduisant la notion d'extension de corps.
\begin{defi}
Étant donné un corps $K$, on appelle \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{extension}} de $K$ tout corps $L$ contenant $K$ et on note  \textcolor{blue}{$L/K$} ou \textcolor{blue}{$L:K$} ou \textcolor{blue}{$K\myarrow L$}.
\end{defi}
\begin{exemples}
\newlist{coloritemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[coloritemize]{label=\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet}}
\begin{coloritemize}
  \item Tout corps de caractéristique $0$ est une extension du corps $\mathds{Q}$.
   En particulier, les inclusions $\mathds{Q} \subset \mathds{R}\subset \mathds{C}$ montrent que $\mathds{R}$ et $\mathds{C}$ sont extensions de $\mathds{Q}$ et que $\mathds{C}$ est extension de $\mathds{R}$.\\
 Utilisons les notations donc on a : $\mathds{C}/\mathds{R}$,   $\ \mathds{C}/\mathds{Q}$,     $\ \mathds{R}/\mathds{Q}$.
 \item Soit $L:=\{p+qi\  |\  (p,q)\in \mathds{Q}\times \mathds{Q}\  et\  i^2=-1 \}$.\\
 On vérifie que $L$ est un sous-corps de $\mathds{C}$ contenant $\mathds{Q}$, donc L est une extension de $\mathds{Q}$, et, $\mathds{C}$ est une extension de $L$.
\end{coloritemize}
\end{exemples}
\begin{defi}
On dira qu'un corps $K'$ est un \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{corps intermédiaire}} pour une extension $L/K$, si 
$K \subset K' \subset L$.
\end{defi}
\section{Degré d'une extension de corps}
\begin{defi}
Soit $L/K$ une extension, la dimension de l'espace vectoriel $L$
sur $K$ s'appel \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{degré}} de l'extension $L/K$. On le note \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{$[L:K]$}}.
\end{defi}
\begin{voc}
Si $L$ est de dimension fini sur $K$, on dit que $L$ est une extension de \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{degré fini}} sur $K$ et 
$[L:K]=dim_KL$. Dans ce cas on note $[L:K]<\infty$. \\
Si $L$ est de dimension infinie sur $K$, on dit que $L$ est une extension de \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{degré infini}} sur $K$. Dans ce cas on note $[L:K]=\infty$.
\end{voc}
\begin{lema}\label{l1}
Soit $L/K$ une extension de degré $[L:K]=1$, $\{\alpha\}$ une base de $L/K$  alors: $$\exists k\in K\ /\  k\alpha=1.$$
\end{lema}
\begin{preuve}
 K est un corps $\implies$ $K\neq\emptyset$ $\implies$ $\exists k_1\in K$ tel que $k_1 \neq 0$, or $\{\alpha\}$ une base de $L/K$ et $k_1 \in$ L \\$\implies$ $k_1=a\alpha$, avec $a\in K$, $k_1$ est inversible dans $K$ $\implies$ 
 $1=k_1^{-1}a \alpha$, par suite il suffit de poser $k=k_1^{-1}a$.\QED
\end{preuve}
\begin{props}
Soit $L/K$ une extension, alors:
$$[L:K]=1 \iff L=K.$$
\end{props}
\begin{preuve}
$(\implies)$\\
Supposons que $[L:K]=1$, d'après le lemme $\ref{l1}$, $\exists k\in K\ /\  k\alpha=1$, donc $\alpha\in K$ (car $\alpha=k^{-1}\in K$).
Or on a: $\forall x\in L$, $x=k'\alpha$ avec $k'\in K$ $\implies$  $x\in K$ (car $K$ est un corps), ce qui donne $L\subset K$, et par définition $K\subset L$, d'où $L=K$.\\
($\Longleftarrow$)\\
Supposons que $L=K$, alors $\{1_L\}$ est une base de L dans K, par suite $[L:K]=1$.\QED
\end{preuve}
\begin{props}\label{p1}
Soient $M/K$ une extension, $L$ un corps intermédiaire de
$M/K$, $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ une base de $L/K$, $(y_j)_{j\in J}$ une base de $M/L$, alors $(x_i y_j)_{(i,j)\in I\times J}$ est une base de $M/K$. 
\end{props}
\begin{preuve}
\textcolor{magenta}{Montrons que $(x_i y_j)_{(i,j)\in I\times J}$ est une famille génératrice de $M/K$}.\\\\
  $(y_j)_{j\in J}$ une base de $M/L$ $\implies$  $\forall z\in M,\   z=\sum\limits_{j\in J} \alpha_j y_j$, où $(\alpha_j)_{j\in J}$ presque nuls dans L. D'une part $\forall j\in J,\ \alpha_j\in L$. D'autre part $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ base de $L/K$ $\implies$ $\alpha_j=\sum\limits_{i\in I} \beta_{ij} x_i$, où $(\beta_{ij})_{i\in I}$  presque nuls dans $K$. On remplace dans z, on trouve  $z=\sum\limits_{j\in J} (\sum\limits_{i\in I} \beta_{ij} x_i)   y_j =\sum\limits_{(i,j)\in I\times J} \beta_{ij} x_i y_j$, on a montré que:
  $$\forall z\in M, \exists (\beta_{ij})_{i\in I}\subset K\ \  tel\ que\ \    z=\sum\limits_{(i,j)\in I\times J} \beta_{ij} x_i y_j.$$
  \textcolor{magenta}{Montrons que $(x_i y_j)_{(i,j)\in I\times J}$ est une famille libre de $M/K$}.\\\\
  Soit $(c_{ij})_{i\in I}\subset K$  tel que $\sum\limits_{(i,j)\in I\times J} c_{ij} x_i y_j=0$, où $(c_{ij})_{i\in I}$  presque nuls dans $K$, alors on a:
  \begin{align*}
 \sum\limits_{(i,j)\in I\times J} c_{ij} x_i y_j=\sum\limits_{j\in J} (\sum\limits_{i\in I} c_{ij} x_i)   y_j=0 & \implies \sum\limits_{i\in I} c_{ij} x_i=0\ \  \big(car:\ (y_j)_{j\in J}\ une\ base\  de\  M/L \big)   \\
 & \implies  c_{ij}=0,\ \forall (i,j)\in I\times J\  \big(car:\ (x_i)_{i\in I}\ une\ base\ de\ L/K\big).
 \end{align*}\QED
 \end{preuve}
 \begin{coro}
 Soient $M/K$ une extension, $L$ un corps intermédiaire de
$M/K$, alors:
$$ [M:K]=[M:L][L:K].$$
De plus: $$ [M:K]<\infty \iff [M:L]<\infty \  et\  [L:K]<\infty .$$
 \end{coro}
 \begin{preuve}
Soit $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ une base de $L/K$, $(y_j)_{j\in J}$ une base de $M/L$, alors d'après la proposition \ref{p1}, $(x_i y_j)_{(i,j)\in I\times J}$ est une base de $M/K$, et on a; 
 \begin{align*}
   [M:K]&= Card\big( \big\{(x_i y_j)_{(i,j)\in I\times J} \big\}\big) \\
 & = Card(I\times J) \\
 & = Card(I)\times Card(J)\\
 & = [M:L][L:K].
 \end{align*}
 L'egalité $ [M:K]=[M:L][L:K],$ justifiée l'équivalence\\
  $$ [M:K]<\infty \iff [M:L]<\infty \  et\  [L:K]<\infty .$$
\QED
 \end{preuve}
 \section{Nombres algébriques - Nombres transcendants}
 \begin{defi}
 Soit $L/K$ une extension de corps, $\alpha \in L$, on dit que $\alpha$ est:\\
 $\centerdot$ \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Algébrique}} sur $K$ si: $\exists P\in K[X]-\{0\}$, tel que $P(\alpha)=0$.\\
$\centerdot$ \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Transcendant}} sur $K$, dans le cas contraire, c'est à dire:
$\forall P\in K[X]-\{0\}$, on a $P(\alpha)\neq 0$.
\end{defi}
\begin{exemples}
\newlist{coloritemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[coloritemize]{label=\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet}}
\begin{coloritemize}
\item Tout élément de K est algébrique sur K.
  \item Les nombres $i$, $\sqrt{2}$  sont algébriques sur $\mathds{Q}$. En effet: $i$ est racine de $X^2+1$, $\sqrt{2}$ est racine de $X^2-2$.
 \item On montre que $\pi$ et $e$ sont transcendants sur $\mathds{Q}$.
\end{coloritemize}
\end{exemples}
\begin{props}
Soit $L/K$ une extension, $\alpha \in L$. Il est équivalent de dire:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item $\alpha$ est algébrique sur K.
\item $[K[\alpha]:K]< \infty $.
\item $ K[\alpha]$ est un corps.
\item $ K[\alpha]$=$ K(\alpha)$.
\item $[K(\alpha):K]< \infty $.
\item $\exists M$ un corps intermédiaire de $L/K$ telles que $[M:K]<$ $\infty$ $\ $ et $\ $ $\alpha \in M$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{props}
\begin{props}
Soient $L/K$ une extension, $\alpha \in L$, $M$ un corps intermédiaire de $L/K$, on a :
$$\alpha\ est\  algébrique\  sur\  K \implies \alpha\  est\  algébrique\  sur\  M.$$
\end{props}
\begin{props}
Soit $L/K$ une extension, $\alpha \in L$ algébrique sur $K$, alors $\exists !Q\in K[X]$
irréductible et unitaire  tel que :
$$\forall P\in K[X],\ \ \ \ \big(\ P(\alpha) = 0 \iff Q|P\ \big).$$
\end{props}
Gardons les hypothèses de cette proposition, on a:
\begin{defi}
Le polynôme $Q$ s'appel polynôme irréductible de l'élément algébrique $\alpha$.\\  On le note : \textcolor{blue}{$Irr(\alpha/K)$} ou \textcolor{blue}{$Irr(\alpha,K)$}.
\end{defi}
\begin{exemples}
\newlist{coloritemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[coloritemize]{label=\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet}}
\begin{coloritemize} 
  \item $\forall \alpha \in K$, on a $Irr(\alpha/K)=X-\alpha$.
  \item $Irr(\sqrt{2}/\mathds{Q})=X^2-2$.
  \item $Irr(\sqrt[3]{2}/\mathds{Q})=X^3-2$.
  \item $Irr(i / \mathds{R})=X^2+1$.
  \item $Irr(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3},\mathds{Q})=X^4-10X^2+1$.
\end{coloritemize}
\end{exemples}
\begin{props}
Soit $L/K$ une extension, $\alpha\in L$ algébrique sur $K$, $Q=Irr(\alpha/K)$, $P\in K[X]$, Il est
équivalent de dire:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item $P$ est de degré le plus petit tel que $P(\alpha)=0$.
\item $P$ est irréductible et $P(\alpha)=0$.
\item $P\thicksim Q$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{props}
\begin{props}
Soit $L/K$ une extension, $\alpha\in L$ algébrique sur $K$, soit $M$ un corps intermédiaire de
$L/K$, on a :$$Irr(\alpha/M)\ |\ Irr(\alpha/K).$$
\end{props}
\begin{props}
Soit $L/K$ une extension, $\alpha\in L$ algébrique sur $K$, $Q=Irr(\alpha/K)$, et $n=d$\textdegree$(Q)$, alors:
$$\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,...\ ,\alpha^{n-1}\}$$
est une \textcolor{blue}{base} de $K(\alpha)/K$.
\end{props}

\begin{defi}
Soit $L/K$ une extension, $\alpha\in L$ algébrique sur $K$, $Q=Irr(\alpha/K)$, le degré de $Q$
\center{s'appel \textcolor{blue}{degré} de l'élément algébrique $\alpha$ sur $K$. On le note \textcolor{blue}{$d$\textdegree$(\alpha/K)$}.}
\end{defi}
\begin{props}
Soit $L/K$ une extension, $(\alpha$,$\beta)$ $\in L^2$  algébriques sur $K$, alors :
$$ \alpha+\beta,\ \  \alpha - \beta,\ \  \alpha \beta,\ \ \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\ (si\  \beta\neq0)$$
sont \textcolor{blue}{algébriques} sur $K$.
\end{props}
\begin{coro}
Soit $L/K$ une extension, l'ensemble des éléments de $L$ algébrique sur $K$ est un
\center{ \textcolor{blue}{corps intermédiaire} de $L/K$.}
\end{coro}
\begin{defi}
Soit $L/K$ une extension, l'ensemble des éléments de $L$ algébrique sur $K$, s'appel
\center{\textcolor{blue}{clôture algébrique} de $K$ dans $L$ (ou de $L/K$).}
\end{defi}
Dans cette section on va définir la notion d'extension algébrique qui a une relation très important avec la clôture algébrique.
\section{Extensions algébriques - Extensions transcendantes}
\begin{defi}
Une extension $L/K$ est dite \textcolor{blue}{algébrique}, si:
\begin{align*}
\forall \alpha \in  L,\  \alpha\  est\  algébrique\  sur\  K.
\end{align*}
Une extension non algébrique est dite extension \textcolor{blue}{transcendante}.
\end{defi}
\begin{remarks}
\textcolor{red}{1)}$\ $ Soit $L/K$ une extension, soit $M$ un corps intermédiaire de $L/K$, alors $M$ est
la clôture algébrique de $L/K$, si et seulement si :
\newlist{coloritemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[coloritemize]{label=\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet}}
\begin{coloritemize}
  \item $M/K$ algébrique.
  \item Pour tout corps intermédiaire $M'$ de $L/K$ on a:
  \begin{align*}
  M'/K\  algébrique \implies M'\subset M.
  \end{align*}
\end{coloritemize}
\textcolor{red}{2)}$\ $On peut aussi définir l'extension algébrique à l'aide de la clôture algébrique, on a :$\ $ \center{$L/K$ algébrique $\iff$ La clôture algébrique de $K$ dans $L$, est $L$.}
\end{remarks}
\begin{props}
Toute extension finie est \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{algébrique}}.
\end{props}
\begin{props}
Soient $L/K$ extension, $M$ corps intermédiaire de $L/K$, alors:
$$ L/K\ est\ algébrique \iff L/M\ \  et\  \ M/K\  sont\  algébriques  $$
\end{props}
\begin{lema}
Soient $L/K$ extension, $M$ corps intermédiaire de $L/K$, $\alpha\in L$, on a:
\begin{align*}
\big(\ \  (\alpha\  algébrique\  sur\  M)\ \  et\ \  (M/K\  algébrique)\ \ \big) \implies (\alpha\  algébrique\  sur\  K)
 \end{align*}
\end{lema}
\begin{props}
Soit $M/M'$ une sous extension d'une extension $L/K$, on a :
$$L/K\ algébrique \implies  M/M'\  algébrique. $$
\end{props}
\begin{props}
Soient $L/K$ une extension, $A\subset L$, alors:
$$\forall \alpha\in A,\  \alpha\ algébrique\  sur\  K \implies K(A)/K\   est\  algébrique. $$
\end{props}
\begin{props}
Soit $L/K$ une extension, $\Omega/L$ une extension, $S\subset\Omega$, on a :
$$L/K\  algébrique\implies  L(S)/K(S)\  algébrique.$$
\end{props}
\begin{defi}
Soient $K_1$ et $K_2$ des sous-corps d'un corps $K$, on appel \textcolor{blue}{sous-corps produit} des sous-corps $K_1$ et $K_2$ le sous-corps de K engendré par $K_1\cup K_2$.
\center{On le note $\textcolor{blue}{K_1K_2}$.}
\end{defi}
\begin{remark}
Voici une autre écriture du sous-corps produit $K$.
$$ K_1 K_2 = K_1(K_2) = K_2(K_1) = P(K_1\cup K_2),$$
où $P$ est le sous-corps \textcolor{blue}{premier} de $K$.
\begin{props}
Soit $L/K$ une extension, $\Omega$ une extension de $L$, soit $M$ un sous-corps de $\Omega$, on a :
$$L/K\  algébrique \implies LM/KM\  algébrique.$$
\end{props}
\end{remark}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you declare that normal font size is `12pt` (as option to `\documentclass`). Is this not sufficient?

Comment: @Zarko i want to use bold font in all text , what is the method ?

Comment: Well, that is not mentioned in your question. Please, edit it and rephrase it such that will be clear what actually is your problem. It may hep (to some degree) to put `\bfseries` after `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

The class options `10pt` or `11pt` or `12pt` change the font size throughout the document. If this is not what you want please revise your question.

For instance the `memoir` class (a superset of the `report` and `book` classes) has the above options but also for 9pt, 14pt, 17pt, 20pt, 25pt, 30pt, 36pt, 48pt and 60pt document font sizes.

Comment: how to use the memoir class in this case please

Comment: @mohammed `texdoc memoir`